# Python configparser: get list of unused entries

Tags: python, configparser

I am using Python's configparser to read an ini file.

After parsing, I would like to print a list of entries that have not been used by the parser to inform the user that they have added entries to their ini file that will be ignored.

Consider an ini file like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
param1 = 1
param2 = 2
param3 = 3
param4 = 4
```

What I would like to have is this:

```
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read(config_path)    
p1 = parser["DEFAULT"]["param1"]
p2 = parser["DEFAULT"]["param2"]
unused = parser["DEFAULT"].get_unused_keys()
```

The last line is made up. I would like the variable 'unused' to contain

```
["param3", "param4"]
```

I haven't found any mention of such a feature in the manual, but I would find it very helpful. I could inherit from ConfigParser and extend all access functions to have a flag that keeps track of whether a specific item was accessed, but I was hoping there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a solution. It is not too elegant but it works. You need to create a child class from `RawConfigParser` class and create a dict variable in your class and extend the `get, _get` methods. As you can see below when you use the `get, getint, getfloat, getboolean` methods to get a value of variable then the related method appends the section and variable to your dict. When you call the  `get_unused_keys` method, it will filter the all available options in a section with the already used options and gives the unused options.

**Complete code:**

```
try:
    import ConfigParser as Cp
except ImportError:
    import configparser as Cp


class ConfigParser(Cp.RawConfigParser):
    """
    ConfigParser class contains the all ConfigParser related implementations.
    """

    used_vars = {}

    def get_unused_keys(self, section):
        all_sections = self.options(section)
        unused_options = [x for x in all_sections if x not in self.used_vars[section]]
        return unused_options

    def get(self, section, option, *, raw=False, vars=None, fallback=Cp._UNSET):
        if section not in self.used_vars:
            self.used_vars[section] = [option]
        else:
            self.used_vars[section].append(option)
        return super().get(section, option, raw=raw, vars=vars, fallback=fallback)

    def _get(self, section, conv, option, **kwargs):
        if section not in self.used_vars:
            self.used_vars[section] = [option]
        else:
            self.used_vars[section].append(option)
        return super()._get(section, conv, option, **kwargs)


parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read("test.ini")

p1 = parser.getint(section="TEST", option="param1")
print("TEST section - param1 = {}".format(p1))
p2 = parser.getboolean(section="TEST", option="param2")
print("TEST section - param2 = {}".format(p2))
print("Unused options in 'TEST' section: {}".format(parser.get_unused_keys("TEST")))
print("")
par2 = parser.get(section="TEST_SEC", option="param2")
print("TEST_SEC section - param2 = {}".format(par2))
print("Unused options in 'TEST_SEC' section: {}".format(parser.get_unused_keys("TEST_SEC")))
```

**Used ini file:**

```
[TEST]
param1 = 1
param2 = True
param3 = 3
param4 = False

[TEST_SEC]
param1 = 89
param2 = Hello World
param3 = 655
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
TEST section - param1 = 1
TEST section - param2 = True
Unused options in 'TEST' section: ['param3', 'param4']

TEST_SEC section - param2 = Hello World
Unused options in 'TEST_SEC' section: ['param1', 'param3']
```

**FYI:**

You shouldn't use `DEFAULT` as name of section because it is a special section and you can get unexpected behavior. I have added `_get` method to my implementations. If you check the original implementation of `ConfigParser`, you can see all type specific getter use this method so it is enough to change. It means now the implementation supports `getint, getfloat, getboolean` methods as well.
I hope my answer help you!

Comment: That is pretty much the option I also implemented in the meantime, but it has the problem that it does not take into account that there are multiple ways to access sections and keys. There are specialized gets (getint, getboolean, etc.), and also the option to access via square brackets [...], maybe more that I am not aware of. I agree that your solution is not too elegant, but it is effective if the limitations are known by the user.

Comment: I accepted your answer because there was no obvious simpler solution that I may have missed. So I finally implemented yours. It has a huge caveat in that it will only work with the get() functions but then it is pretty clean. Could you do me a favor and add the three other get functions (getint, getboolean, getfloat) so that other users may find a more complete solution to the problem? Also I found that instead of copying the get() function you can simply call it via super().get(). That way the whole thing can be implemented in ~50 lines of code including all get() variants

Comment: First of all thanks you to accepted my answer. I have edited my answer and now the implementation can support getint, getfloat, getboolean methods as well. On the other hand, sorry but I don't understand what you mean under `super()`. We need to re-implement the `get` and `_get` methods so the simple method calling is not option but it is possible that I don't understand your point so please correct me if I am wrong. I hope my edited implementation more efficient and can help more others.

Comment: Assuming you define used_vars as defaultdict, you can simply define the get function as     def get(self, section, option, *, raw=False, vars=None, fallback=_UNSET):
        self.used_vars[section].append(option)
        return super().get(section, option, raw=raw, vars=vars, fallback=fallback). Sorry for the bad formatting. So you basically do your dictionary update and then call the original get function via super().get(). No need to reimplement it.

Comment: Also for the sake of readability, I would suggest you only use one section of code in your answer. The history of your edits is probably not very useful for posterity.

Comment: I already understand you point about `super()` and I totally agree with you. I have changed my code and edited my answer. I really thanks your suggestions.

Comment: One last concern: You overrode _get(), but the getint() function internally calls _get_conv(). Also I would feel a bit hesistant about overriding private functions. How about instead you don't override _get() at all, but instead you override all three getint/getboolean/getfloat functions? Also if you use defaultdict instead of dict, you can reduce the number of lines in your overridden function (see my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Make a `set` of allowed keys. Then create a `set` of used keys. Substract the alllowed keys from the used keys.

```
In [1]: import configparser                                                                              

In [2]: config = configparser.ConfigParser()                                                             
Out[2]: <configparser.ConfigParser at 0x80a0624d0>

In [3]: config.read_string("""[DEFAULT] 
   ...: param1 = 1 
   ...: param2 = 2 
   ...: param3 = 3 
   ...: param4 = 4""")                                                                                   

In [4]: allowed_keys = {'param1', 'param2'}                                                              
Out[4]: {'param1', 'param2'}

In [5]: usedkeys = set(config['DEFAULT'].keys())                                                         
Out[5]: {'param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4'}

In [6]: illegal_keys = usedkeys - allowed_keys                                                           
Out[6]: {'param3', 'param4'}
```

With the same technique you could have section names that are allowed, and parameters that are only allowed in certain sections.

For example, you could make `allowed_keys` into a `dict` of `set`s:

```
In [7]: allowed_keys = {'DEFAULT': {'param1', 'param2'}, 'section1': {'param3', 'param4'}}               
Out[7]: {'DEFAULT': {'param1', 'param2'}, 'section1': {'param3', 'param4'}}
```

So you could first look at the section names, then at the allowed parameter names for the allowed section.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I could do that and I considered this option, but that leads to redundant data, since (1) I have to keep a list of allowed keys and (2) I have to parse the allowed keys into variables for handling them. It could happen that I add or remove a parsed parameter and forget to add or remove it in the list. So, noted that this is an option, but I had something more robust in mind.

Comment: @Cerno Since you want to be able to reject parameters that are not allowed, you have to keep a data structure of allowed *somewhere*.

Comment: True, but in my case I want to print a summary as information to the user. If I wanted to raise an error you would be right, but that was not my intention.